# Entry Poster IMdb

Tags: channel-fields

I am trying to use entry_poster_imdb

https://github.com/intoeetive/entry_poster_imdb

Is it possible to create fields automatically in a field group, corresponding to the IMdb fields which are pulled from IMdb?

[image: IMDB]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that is not possible. You need to create channel fields and map those to IMDB data fields in add-on settings first.

Of course (if you are programmer) feel free to develop such feature and submit pull request, as this add-on is open source.

Comment: I did create the fields and mapped them. However, seems like an entry is getting posted however it cannot be edited as a channel error is encountered. Need to look at the code. Thanks for the suggestion. Will try to use OMDb API to see if I can work on this addon.

Comment: Check the author_id the entry posted under. I believe it's hardcoded in the module. Or there might be some other issue, depending on the error